# Problem AVR stuck and program counter lost ...?

Tags: rest, stack, embedded, avr

I am facing a strange behavior i am working on project using ATMEL MCU (ATMEGA328p)   with huge amount with strings so i stored it in flash memory and during run time i read it from flash memory and send it via UART.
i don't know if this the problem or not because i was using the same technique before in other projects but what is different here the amount of strings larger than before.

```
void PLL_void_UART_SendSrting_F(U8_t* RXBuffer,const char * str , U8_t UART_No)
{
    unsigned int _indx=0;
    memset(RXBuffer,'\0', A9G_RX_Index);    // Initialize the string
    RXBuffer[A9G_RX_Index-1]='\0';

    //  cli();
    while((RXBuffer[_indx]=pgm_read_byte(&(*str))))
    {
        str++;
        _indx++;
        _delay_ms(5);
    }
    //  sei();
    PLL_void_UART_SendSrting(RXBuffer,0);

}
```

But after awhile the whole program stuck and even after doing hard reset , to work again i should unplug and plug the power again.

Notes :- 
- I am sure that hard reset working 
- I am using timers in background as system tick .

Comment: "But after awhile the whole program stuck" doesn't really help. You should try to narrow the problem down and explain exactly when the code gets "stuck" and what happens. Its best if you create a minimal but complete code example that still crashes. A few things to check: 1. Is "A9G_RX_Index" definitely the size of "RXBuffer" (buffer overflow)? 2. Is *str definitely always \0 terminated (deadlock)?

Comment: Really i don't know what is main reason because it happened by luck.
the behavior like that i am toggling led each one second as sign the board working and suddenly it stop. i tried to rest it with no response.
and also i reprogrammed it again with same .hex file MCU didn't work and i should  flash different one first .
for RX buffer i just use it because i though if i read from the flash fast it damage it so i used that buffer to read slowly and send it via serial to GSM .

Comment: Kindly check how strings located in memory and it end with '\0'https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lCZZxOTW4UZjfusH9tTPKGkgnhnVG10k/view?usp=sharing

Comment: `pgm_read_byte(&(*str))))` looks fishy. The `&*` cancel each other out so you could just write `pgm_read_byte(str)`. But you probably can't since the data is const qualified, so it would seem you have a design mistake in there somewhere. Similarly, `_delay_ms(5);` doesn't look correct... why hardcode for baudrate 200 bps? Instead you should be waiting on an UART rx flag to be set in some register.

Comment: @Lundin : The point about the delay is an interesting observation, but it is not related to the baud rate - that just delays loading the buffer - the UART send appears to be done _after_ the loop.  It seems to serve no purpose at all.

Comment: @Lundin i edited my code but still MCU stuck after while and hard rest not working at all. program work again after restart the power. do you know what is the reason for that

Comment: @MuhammadAboulhadeed How could I possibly know why your program suddenly gets stuck without seeing the code? There could be any number of reasons. You could post a new question about that problem.

Comment: thank you i will try to fix it

Comment: Hard reset absolutely the same as power-up reset. So, if part still not working after the hard reset, that means you either have malfunctioning part or schematic problem. Try to replace the MCU, if it still not works, see is it connected properly, is the power enough, is there any other part of the code that interacts with other inputs, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for support 
I found the issues, it was because watch dog timer keep the MCU in restart mode even when i press the hardware rest. this is because, i was considering all registers,flags back to its default value after rest.[WDT Block Digram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5BKAo.png)

i was doing that in code when MCU start execution the code like that :

```
U8_t PLL_U8_System_Init()
{
static U8_t SetFalg=0;

PLL_void_TimerInit();                               // General Timer Initialize                         
PLL_WDT_Init();                                     // Initialize WDT and clear  WDRF 
wdt_enable(WDTO_8S);                                // Enable WDT Each 2 S
........
}
```

but once WDT occurred and rest the program then CPU found WDRF flag is set so it keep in rest for ever since i did power rest.

**Solution** 
i have to clear WDT timer once program start first, before execute any code and its work

```
U8_t PLL_U8_System_Init()
{
static U8_t SetFalg=0;

PLL_void_TimerInit();                               // General Timer Initialize                         
PLL_WDT_Init();                                     // Initialize WDT and clear WDRF   
wdt_enable(WDTO_8S);                                // Enable WDT Each 2 S
........
}
```

**this is what written in data sheet**

Note:  If the Watchdog is accidentally enabled, for example by a runaway pointer or
brown-out condition, the device will be reset and the Watchdog Timer will stay enabled. If
the code is not set up to handle the Watchdog, this might lead to an eternal loop of timeout resets. To avoid this situation, the application software should always clear the
Watchdog System Reset Flag (WDRF) and the WDE control bit in the initialization
routine, even if the Watchdog is not in use.

Answer (score 0):

The code is unsafe; you do nothing to prevent a buffer overrun.

Consider the safer, and simpler:

```
void PLL_void_UART_SendString_F( U8_t* RXBuffer, const char* str, U8_t UART_No )
{
    unsigned index = 0 ;
    RXBuffer[A9G_RX_Index - 1] = '\0' ;

    while( index < A9G_RX_Index - 1 && 
           0 != (RXBuffer[index] = pgm_read_byte( &str[index] )) )
    {
        index++ ;
    }

    PLL_void_UART_SendSrting( RXBuffer, 0 ) ;
}
```

Even then you have to be certain `RXBuffer` is appropriately sized and `str` is nul terminated.

Comment: Thank you in advance but i tried above code but still the same problem. after while every thing stuck . even WDT enabled but after stuck WDT not work and hardware rest

Comment: @MuhammadAboulhadeed : OK, but as indicated in the comments to your question, you have provided insufficient information.  I can only address issues with teh code posted that _might_ cause the symptoms you observe (which are them selves unclear).  You need to fix the question.